# How to custom format numeric columns in shiny renderTable?

Tags: r, shiny, format

I would like to custom format the numeric columns in my table. I would like to have the p-values in scientific format, and the other numeric columns with 0 or 2 decimals. How can I do this? I have tried

```
output$addtable <- renderTable({ ...} , digits = -2)
```

but that converts all numeric columns into scientific format.

```
output$addtable <- renderTable({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    d=dataset[which(dataset$gene==input$textgene),]
    names(d)=c("Gene","P","CmafUsed","NsnpsUsed","MinP","MinGene","Ratio")
    if(dim(d)[1]==0) {'No entry found'} else return(d)    
  })
```

What I am looking for is to have:

```
Gene    P       CmafUsed    NsnpsUsed   MinP    MinGene Ratio
GENE1   1.50E-05    0.20    12        4.62E-05  GENE2   1.11
```

Comment: When I want total control I usually convert them all to character using `sprintf`. Anything else is unreliable really.

Comment: Sometimes I even have an entirely separate data frame just for display. Which is how `ggplot` does it for example.

Comment: Thank you, `sprintf` worked great!

Comment: since you mentioned scientific: An alternative would be `format(..., scientific = TRUE)`,...

Comment: Mind if I write it up and you accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
  d$P <- sprintf("%7.2e",d$P)
  d$MinP <- sprintf("%7.2e",d$MinP)
```

I like using `sprintf` because it works in many languages, so I have less to remember. But `format` like BigDataScientist suggested will work just as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a list of columns/list of formats?  I have a large table and would like to avoid formatting each variable line-by-line.

Comment: use `sapply`? Not sure I really understand what you want. I would try something, and if you can't get it to work post it as a question with your example.

Comment: Do we need to clone the table as in the OP's question if we wish to avoid modifying the column in the original table? I think I've read R is copy-on-modify, but data.tables are more like pass-by-reference?

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned scientific, this comes to mind:

```
df = data.frame(P = 1e-6, Rest = 1e-6)
df$P <- format(df$P, scientific = FALSE)
df$Rest <- format(df$Rest, scientific = TRUE)
```